# how to store ldap data in relational database (MySQL)

Tags: hibernate, ldap, spring-ldap

Is is possible to store ldap data in a relational database (mysql for example)?

Is it possible to create an DAO Repository that can map between java objects and ldap entries queries to make transactions using using spring ldap odmManager and hibernate.

Comment: See for example http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/978.html

Comment: I am using ApacheDS library in my spring boot application, I created an embedded ldap server and now I want to map map entries received from an ldap client to beans that can I store to database (mysql)